# \addcontentsline is causing indents in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, indentation

I am generating a document with multiple custom tables and sections that don't follow standard numbering and am using \addcontentsline to place them in the TOC as below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
%begin revision history
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REVISION HISTORY}
    \begin{raggedright}
    {\bf\LARGE{REVISION HISTORY}}\\
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
    Add Revision History. If initial release, delete page.\\
%end revision history
\bigskip %replace \newpage for code snippet
%begin table of contents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    {\bf\LARGE{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}\\
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
    \end{raggedright}
    \begin{center}
    \makeatletter
    \@starttoc{toc}% Print Table of Contents
    \makeatother
    \end{center}
%end table of contents
\bigskip %replace \newpage for code snippet
%begin list of figures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \begin{raggedright}
    {\bf\LARGE{LIST OF FIGURES}}\\
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
    Add List of Figures. If not utilized, delete page.
    \end{raggedright}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces a table of contents with the first item as I would expect and the next two indented, even though they are the same depth.

[image: TOC Indent]

Why are second and third lines of the TOC indented and how do I fix that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `\section{REVISION HISTORY}`?  Custom tables and section numbering aren't too hard to fix.

Comment: you are missing the chapter entry. Why are you using the report class and then only sections?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm pretty new to LaTeX, but report had templating that matched closest with the MSWord template I'm imitating. I guess I can go back to article and try to reformat there. I'll also try swapping to chapters and see how that goes.

Comment: @Teepeemm my actual document has a mix of numbered and unnumbered sections, so I would be using \section* and then still have to use \addcontentsline.

Comment: Don't use `\bf` which was deprecated over 25 years ago. Use either `{\bfseries text}` or `\textbf{<text>}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered accidentally that wrapping the @starttoc{toc} in a centered environment is what was causing the odd indent. Removing the \begin and \end {center} lines fixed the issue.